# How to sync two ASP.NET Membership databases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I have a local and an azure ASP.NET Membership database.  I need to be sync them both.  Wondering if anyone has found a easy way to do this?  The table structure seems simple enough but would rather pull from azure than push.  Is there a routine or tool I do not know about to  do this by now?

Thanks

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

This would be a suitable job for the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753).

You create a service or scheduled task that makes the necessary calls. Have this running on your server and you can pull from the Azure database and sync with the local one. It can be set up to sync one way or two ways.